# Как поделить одну страничку на два блока?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, мне нужно в html документе прописать чудо код,
чтоб сделалось 2 блока (1 - Контент, 2 - Правая панель).

Вот код:

```
<STYLE>
.menu {
    font-family: 'Neucha', cursive;
}

.menu a{
    /* Округления START */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* Округления END */
    text-decoration:none; /* Убираем нижнюю линию под ссылкой */
    color:#2277B0;    /* Цвет ссылки */
    padding:4px;    /* Внутренний отступ */
}

.menu a:hover{
    border:1px solid #E7E7E7; /* Обводка */
    /* Градиент START */
    background: rgb(249,249,249);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(249,249,249,1) 1%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,rgba(249,249,249,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(237,237,237,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(249,249,249,1) 1%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(249,249,249,1) 1%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(249,249,249,1) 1%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(249,249,249,1) 1%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 );
    /* Градиент END */
}

td, th {
padding:5px; /* Внутренний отступ */
background-color:#478CFB;    /* Фон */
color:#fff;        /* Цвет */
font:8pt 'Bad Script', cursive;    /* Размер, семейство шрифта */
}

table, tr, td, th {
border:1px solid #5C98FC; /* Обводка */
border-collapse:collapse; /* Убираем двойные линии */
}

.table {
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Округления */
-moz-border-radius: 10px;    /* Округления */
border-radius:10px;            /* Округления */
display:inline-block;    /* Делаем так, что бы блок обтягивал таблицу */
overflow:hidden;     /* Убираем все, что не поместилось в блок */
}

table td:nth-child(odd) {
background-color:#5493FC; /* Цвет фона */
}

td:hover {
background-color:#5493FC; /* Цвет фона */
}
</STYLE>

<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Neucha&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<br>
<div class="menu">
<a href="http://aukro.ua/my_page.php?uid=20188849">Обо мне</a><a href="http://aukro.ua/listing/user.php?us_id=20188849">Мои товары</a><a href="http://aukro.ua/show_user.php?uid=20188849">Отзывы</a><a href="http://aukro.ua/SendMailToUser.php?userId=20188849">Задать вопрос</a>
</div>
<br>

<div class="table">
<div class="leftboard">
<table cellspacing="0">
<tr><th>Характеристики</th> <th>ZOPO ZP700</th><tr>
<tr><td>Тип</td> <td>Смартфон</td><tr>
<tr><td>Тип корпуса</td> <td>моноблок</td><tr>
<tr><td>Габариты</td> <td>Вес: 148 гр<br>Размеры: 126×68×11 мм.</td><tr>
<tr><td>Количество SIM – карт</td> <td>2 активных sim – карты(WCDMA+GSM/GSM+GSM)</td><tr>
<tr><td>Операционная система</td> <td>Android 2.3</td><tr>
<tr><td>Процессор</td> <td>MediaTek MT6575</td><tr>
<tr><td>Стандарт связи</td> <td>WCDMA/HSDPA 900/2100MHz<br>GSM 900/1800/1900MHZ</td><tr>
<tr><td>Дисплей</td> <td>Емкостной AVS экран с поддержкой Multitouch<br>материал - стекло.<br>4,3 дюйма QHD<br>16 млн.цветов<br>Разрешение экрана: QHD, 960х540 пикс.</td><tr>
<tr><td>Функции памяти</td> <td>RAM: 1 Гб.<br>ROM: 4 Гб.<br>Слот для карт памяти microSD (TransFlash), расширение максимально до 32 Gb.</td><tr>
<tr><td>Беспроводные технологии</td> <td>Bluetooth BT 3.0, EDR.<br>Wi-Fi b/g/n<br>GPS</td><tr>
<tr><td>Камера</td> <td>Основная 8 Мп, автоматический фокус, цифровой зум<br>Фронтальная 0,3 Мп</td><tr>
<tr><td>Аккумуляторная батарея</td> <td>Li-Ion, 1700 мАч</td><tr>
<tr><td>Разъем под наушники</td> <td>3.5 мм</td><tr>
<tr><td>TV</td> <td>Отсутствует.</td><tr>
<tr><td>Комплект поставки</td> <td>Мобильный телефон<br>Батарея - 1 шт.<br>Зарядное устройство<br>USB-кабель<br>Стерео гарнитура<br>Руководство пользователя на  английском языке.</td><tr>
<tr><td>Цвет корпуса</td> <td>Черный.</td><tr></table>
</div></div>
```

Нужно сделать, чтоб было как на картинке:

[image]

Comment: Первый - float:left; второй - float:right;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кто то использует `float`. Конечно, это тоже вариант, а что если необходимо будет переставить контентный блог на место правого, что тогда лезть в код и перебивать float'ы. Есть вариант который я использую.

---

содержание html

```
<!--wrapper start-->
<div class="wrapper">

<!--content start-->
<div class="content">
   Содержание контента тут может быть меню промо ролики и т.д.
</div>
<!--content end-->

<!--sidebar start-->
<div class="sidebar">
   Боковая панель она может распологаться как слева так и справа
</div>
<!--sidebar end-->
```

</div>
  <!--wrapper end-->

---

теперь отрегулируем все в CSS

```
/* wrapper start*/
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  }
/* wrapper end*/

/* content start*/
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 698px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  }
/* content end*/

/* sidebar start*/
.sidebar {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 258px;
   vertical-align: top;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   }
/* sidebar end*/
```

---

И так два блока мы создали. Теперь же к чему все это. Допустим, нам необходимо поменять местами левую и правую часть, просто идем в html копируем весь блок [content] и со всем содержимым внутри его и просто вставляем ниже блока  [sidebar] и  все!!! т.е должно получиться так. (И заметьте мы даже стили не трогали)

содержание html

```
<!--wrapper start-->
<div class="wrapper">
```

(ТУТ ВЫРЕЗАЛИ КОНТЕНТ БЛОК)

```
<!--sidebar start-->
<div class="sidebar">
   Боковая панель она может распологаться как слева так и справа
</div>
<!--sidebar end-->

(ЗДЕСЬ ЕГО ПОСТАВИМ)

<!--content start-->
<div class="content">
   Содержание контента тут может быть меню промо ролики и т.д.
</div>
<!--content end-->

</div>
<!--wrapper end-->
```

P.S. "wrapper" тэг тут нужен обертки всего содержимого сайта в принципе для этого служит "body", но я бы не советовал его игнорировать.

P.S.S. да, и я бы не использовал td tr и т.д они уже не актуальны для списков или как говориться для меню лучше исползовать "улки с вложенными лишками" `<ul> <li> </li></ul>`.

Comment: Соглашаюсь, хороший вариант. Следуют обратить внимание на то, что инлайновые и инлайн-блоковые элементы получают некоторые свойства текста. В том числе и замену всех разделителей между ними пробелом. Видимо по этому у вас сумарная ширина контента и сайдбара на 4px меньше враппера. Вопрос: вы уверенны, что пробел всегда будет шириной в 4px?

Comment: У этого способа, кстати, есть еще один большой плюс: инлайновые и инлайн-блоковые элементы сохраняют вертикальное выравнивание по базовой линии между собой. Что очень удобно для идущих друг за другом input type text и input type submit, например.

Comment: 4px потому что border:1px добавляет к общей ширине блока, я border поставил чтобы наглядно было видно, а вообще он не нужен. Убрать бордер (border: none;) и можно полностью указать 700px и 260px.
Прошу прощения также забыл вставить выравнивание по верху исправил в коде

Comment: Прошу прощения. Бордюр упустил :). Может еще чего упустил, но в том виде, в котором код представлен сейчас, блоки не выстраиваются друг за другом:
http://jsfiddle.net/E6Pa7/
Дело как раз в пробеле который появляется между блоками из-за инлайновости. Если исключить в HTML все, что пораждает этот пробел (все разделители), то пример работает:
http://jsfiddle.net/E6Pa7/1/

Если не брать этот пробел в учет, то решение не стабильное. Даже если вы будите писать HTML не допуская разделителей, то не факт, что тот кто будет прогать не порадит их там.

Comment: Стабильное решение?!...хм... для меня данный отступ между блоками не критичен, все равно при верстке так или иначе идет внутренние padding  и можно где то на 2-6 пикселей тот или иной блок урезать. Тогда получается что лучшее решение это применить Float. Пока на ваше замечание у меня нет ответа, если он появится, то я обязательно отпишу в данном посте (есть над чем подумать).

Comment: Cypher - я нашел ответ на ваш вопрос, когда используем элемент display: inline-block; то по умолчания появляется отступ в 3-4 пикселя, поэтому чтобы они выстроились по горизонтали то необходимо размер каждого блока сократить на 3-4 пикселя. Т.е если у нас wrapper имеет ширину 960px, то левый блок должен быть например не 400 пикселей, а 396-397 пикселей. Правый 556-557. Это тот самый пробел про который вы спросили.

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте ширину и [обтекание](http://htmlbook.ru/css/float) обеим колонкам. Создайте класс сбрасывающий обтекание.

```
.menu {
    width: 260px;
    float: right;
}

.table {
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
}

.clearer {
    clear: both;
}
```

После этих блоков добавьте тег cо сбросом обтекания. Иначе следующий тег продолжит обтекать последний блок.

```
<div class="menu">
    ...
</div>
<div class="table">
    ...
</div>

<br class="clearer">
```

PS: ширину можете задать как в пикселях, так и в процентах. Не забывайте, что значения отступов и бордюры будут так же добавляться в ширину. Если нужны "полурезиновые" макеты, то обратите внимание на [что-нибудь готовое.](http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/), так как это на порядок сложнее.

**UPD:** время и опыт показали, что обтекание не самый лучший инструмент для создания колонок да и вообще какой-либо разметки. А вот inline-block (см. ответ nosensus) железобетонный механизм ([если разобраться с пробелами](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)) и самый лучший друг верстальщика :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<frameset cols='*,50%' FRAMEBORDER=0 FRAMESPACING=0 BORDERCOLOR=#000000> 
<frame SRC='url' NAME='name_1' SCROLLING='AUTO' FRAMEBORDER=0>
<frame SRC='url' NAME='name' SCROLLING='AUTO' FRAMEBORDER=0>
</frameset>
```

или

```
<table width=1000 cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">
<tr align="left">
<td><!-- Блок №1 --></td>
</tr>
<tr align="left">
<td><!-- Блок №2 --></td>
</tr>
</table>
```